# Raspberry PI B+ color screen and NOOBS

Tags: noobs

I am new user for Raspberry Pi so I get Raspberry pi B+ and download NOOBS on Raspberry Pi website. After that I unzip that file and copy these files to SD card. Then when I power up, it display the color screen. Why is that? There is no kernel.img in SD card. Where can I get it? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you "copy the files" to the SD card?

Comment: Unzip that file and copy all files and copy to SD card

Comment: What display do you have connected?

Comment: Samsung TV with HDMI

Comment: One last question - NOOBS, or NOOBS Lite?

Comment: NOOBS not NOOBS Lite

Answer (score 2):

NOOBS isn't an OS in its own right, it is merely an installer that allows you to install other operating systems.

As a result it doesn't have a kernel as such, but a "recovery" utility.

The sequence is basically thus:

1. The chip finds the file *bootcode.bin* and executes it.
2. *bootcode.bin* finds *recovery.elf* and executes it.
3. *recovery.elf* loads the RAM filesystem *recovery.rfs* into memory and mounts it.
4. *recovery.elf* then passes control to the installation system in the RAM FS.

It's the file *recovery.elf* which draws the pretty rainbow box on the screen, and the programs contained in the recovery RAM FS that would replace it with other things.

Normally it should present you with a list of available operating systems to install (it comes bundled with Raspbian - others can download through the internet). You would select one of these to install, and the SD card would be repartitioned and the operating system installed onto it - thus destroying NOOBS in the process.

The instructions specifically specify a specific way of formatting the SD card using the [SD Association's Formatting Tool](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4). That is specified, along with the other steps you must take when doing the formatting, in the file INSTRUCTIONS-README.txt in the NOOBS ZIP file.

Please ensure that you have formatted the SD card properly using this method.

---

Update:

You're telling me there are files missing from the SD card.  If your Pi is doing what is shown in that video, then all the files are there perfectly fine.

It's getting part way through running the kernel, so it's booting linux fine.  What is happening then though, I suspect, is that the kernel is enabling some hardware drivers (Ethernet?) which are then causing an increase in current draw.  Your power supply (whatever that may be) isn't up to the task, so the voltage drops, and the BOR circuit in the BCM chip detects the drop in voltage and resets the whole board, disabling the extra drivers so it boots up again - until the drivers are turned on again by the kernel.

Comment: I download NOOBS and copy these file to SD card after that what do i want to do ? can you enplane step by step ?

Comment: Read the file INSTRUCTIONS-README.txt - it explains it step by step.

Comment: Your Pi will now boot into NOOBS and should display a list of operating systems that you can choose to install.
If your display remains blank, you should select the correct output mode for your display by pressing one of the following number keys on your keyboard:
1. HDMI mode - this is the default display mode.
2. HDMI safe mode - select this mode if you are using the HDMI connector and cannot see anything on screen when the Pi has booted.
3. Composite PAL mode - select either this mode or composite NTSC mode if you are using the composite RCA video connector.
4. Composite NTSC mode

Comment: I can't understand dear :( in my os folder only have two folders. these are Data_Partition and Raspbian.

Comment: Then there's no hope for you.  Scrap NOOBS, and download the Raspbian image instead. Follow the instructions for writing that image to an SD card using appropriate image writing software.

Comment: I tried using Raspbian image. Then i got another problem. That is loader.bin is not in folder. then display is again and aging running.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions *to the letter* for installing your image to your SD card? http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md

Comment: Yeah I use this method loader.bin is not in folder other files are ok

Comment: Maybe you have AV software that's deleting files randomly that it takes an aversion to. Maybe you have a virus that is deleting random files. Maybe you're just cursed. Just buy a pre-installed SD card and have done with it, and keep it well away from your computer.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04OEcZMxyl0 now work like this. I am not installed AV software.

Comment: And what are you using to power your rPi?